# Continuity on a union

Tags: general-topology

Let $X= \bigcup X_n$ be a countable union of subsets $X_1\subset X_2\subset \dots$ and let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Given a function $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $f|_{X_n}$ is continuous, is it necessarily true, that $f$ is continuous on $X$?

I have been trying to think of a counter-example but could find one although it does not quite seem to be enough information on $f$ for it to be continuous. First of all I am interested in a proof or counter-example for this statement, but after all I am also looking for a maybe similar statement that is true.

**Edit:** If I understood both answers right, additionally assuming that all closures $\bar X_n= X$ would suffice for the assertion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is true for all spaces $Y$ if and only if $X$ has the [colimit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)) topology with respect to the spaces $X_i$, more traditionally known as the [coherent topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology). A counterexample is given by a countable set $X$ equipped with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness) and $X_i$ an increasing sequence of finite sets whose union is $X$ (for example $X = \mathbb{Z}, X_i = [-i, i]$). The colimit topology with respect to the $X_i$ is the discrete topology.

**Edit:** $\overline{ X_i} = X$ (which is equivalent to $\overline{ X_1 } = X$) is also not enough to guarantee that you have the coherent topology. Take the above example $X = \mathbb{Z}, X_i = [-i, i]$ with the cofinite topology and remove all of the non-empty open sets that don't include $\{ 0 \}$ (so a combination of the cofinite topology and the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology)). Then each $X_i$ is dense but the above problem still stands: the colimit topology with respect to the $X_i$ is the particular point topology on $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @Peter: that's sort of a strange condition, but okay.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you did that. I wish I could upvote your answer once more...

Comment: well this strange condition naturally comes from a specific problem, that I was hoping to solve myself with a statement like the above. I am slowly suspecting that I cannot solve my problem by a similar statement.

Comment: I now posted my original problem in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/about-the-limit-of-a-uniformly-converging-function-sequence

Comment: @Qiaochu: I'd like to clear up the terminology. Wiki defines the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) (or *weak topology* or *limit topology* or *projective topology*) and [final topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) (or *strong topology* or *inductive topology*). **Colimit topology** is then final topology, right?

Comment: @Leon: sort of, but they're defined at different levels of generality. The colimit is a topological space one can cook up given a diagram of spaces, whereas the final topology is a topology that one specifies on a set given some functions into it from spaces. So the former can be described entirely in $\text{Top}$ and does not require that you construct the space beforehand, whereas the latter requires an existing set and needs to be described in $\text{Set}$ (and $\text{Top}$).

Comment: Hmm, in Dieck's *Algebraic topology* (p.10), it says "Suppose a space $X$ is the union of subspaces $X_j$ $j\!\in\!J$. We say $X$ carries the colimit topology with respect to this family if ($C$ is closed in $X$ if and only if ($X_j\!\cap\!C$ is closed in $X_j$ for each $j\!\in\!J$))." This is then exactly the final topology for the inclusions $f_j\!:X_j\!\hookrightarrow\!X$, correct? I'm just trying to understand why Wiki says initial and limit topologies are equal, but with final topology, it doesn't even mention the colimit topology.

Comment: @Leon: yes. Wikipedia is not perfect.

Comment: Ok, thanks :), I'll edit Wiki.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not true. Take $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \neq 0$. If $X_{n} = \{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n-1},\ldots,1\}$ and  $X = \bigcup_{n} X_n$ is viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $f|_{X_n}$ is definitely continuous, but $f$ is clearly not continuous as a function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$.

In fact, in order for your condition to hold for all $f: X \to Y$, where $Y$ is allowed to be any space, it is necessary and sufficient that your space $X$ be equipped with the [final topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) induced by the inclusions $X_{i} \to X$.

Comment: please note the edit

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I worked out a special case of this problem, where $X$ is a metric space and $Y=\mathbb{R}$. Then having each $X_n$ be open is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: I tried to use it in this case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/about-the-limit-of-a-uniformly-converging-function-sequence. But we could solve it differently.